# Computerized Chess games Analysis

Tags: analysis, learning, software

I am looking for the ultimate chess game analysis tool
I used lucas chess which is great but lack some details, I also tried creatica https://chessgame-analyzer.creatica.org/ which is good also but again lack some ideas and information.
are there any other tools that are free and better than the two above and or have some other point of view and can work offline.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What "ideas and information" are you especially interested in?

Comment: The ultimate analysis tool is the human brain

Comment: I need useful information from the analysis provided by a reliable source, and that's currently not me. chess engines are my best choice for now. I also need to link my moves in the opening phase to other good players moves and the best advisor possible, and I want to take that and print it out to read in the car or coffee shop or library or anywhere else.
it is good to know about any other computerized method of analysis that I'm not aware of. I don't like variations and evaluations only, I need more.
A full blown computerized chess coach is great thing to look for.

Comment: @David How can I get one of those? Mine seems defective.

Comment: @WassimSaeed what's the ultimate purpose of your work? Chess improvement? Coaching? Assisting another player? Writing a book?

Comment: @David I have three goals here 2 of them serves my improving at chess efforts and the third one is to assist a couple of friends.
Goal 1 is to analyze my own games and find everything to be found about them like: who played this opening what are the statistical outcomes of the used lines in both computer and human games and also (as a sub set) grand masters games, I want to know what I missed,what I have plundered...etc.
Goal 2: to analyze the games that I see in the books I'm reading, find the context and the actual quality of the games that some authors are just throwing at us.

Comment: @David 
Goal 3: helping a friend by analyzing his games, he is a good chess player but has no computer skills.

Comment: @WassimSaeed I think your goals 1 and 2 can be achieved with a good use of a database and an engine like Stockfish. No additional tool will provide much benefit. As for goal 3, you don't need computer skills to analyze a game of chess.

Comment: As of now advanced programs can provide only basic commentary and advice. Fritz (not free) can comment like that but it's geared to beginners and amateurs (pins, double attacks, and themes like that). As to ideas and plans, they are in chess textbooks. Some books have even amateur games annotated in great detail; it's very instructive. It would be interesting to see improvements in programs in this regard. If you are a pro player (need stats, probabilities, which GM played, ...) you might need a pro non-free program that has it all. Downvoting this question and answer to it was not warranted.

Comment: At you looking for *free* software? If not, have you tried ChessBase?

Comment: @Hauptideal of course I need it to be free, if you check the comment before you you'll find that Fritz is geared toward 'beginners and amateurs', and it is not free.

Comment: Fritz/ChessBase programs are geared mainly towards professionals!!! It's just that verbal commentary (pins, double attacks, and themes like that) and explanations provided in its automatic analysis are geared towards beginners and amateurs. The analysis itself can be tweaked depending on the strength of the player. It shows lines and variations but it doesn't quite cut it for pro level because you need to delve deeper into subvariations manually at serious level. Also verbal commentary/analysis is not needed (for pros). You can switch it off completely so that it doesn't irritate.

Comment: Not to be misunderstood again. I'm not saying that Fritz/Chessbase analysis is not good. It's superb. It's just that for pro players automatic analysis is not gonna quite cut it without doing some lines and subvariations manually. It doesn't matter what program is used, at serious level some extra delving is necessary in manual mode. Of course, you can manually expand/change Fritz/ChessBase auto analysis.

Comment: @KenDraco I have seen videos and read articles about Fritz analysis and the thing hasn't changed a bit in 10 years or more. there are some new ideas in this subject, You can check Lucas analysis and Creatica to understand my POV.

Comment: I've just installed the latest Lucas out of curiosity. It's always been a beautiful program for amateurs. It still is and it's still free. And I've just uninstalled Lucas. Its analysis and play is out of wack. Creators crazily slapped Elo scale (and other such things) onto its engines which is ridiculous. Not enough professionals probably tested it and not enough correlation was made. Its analysis is a joke even for a club player. I'm sorry. I don't understand what analysis you want from professional programs. Just use amateur free stuff like Lucas and be done with it. Forget ChessBase/Fritz.

Comment: A piece of general advice for those who aspire towards high club, semi pro and even pro level but on a very tight budget. There are second hand things, like on Ebay, where old versions of professional ChessBase/Fritz programs are much cheaper. Yes, they will lack updated database with the latest tournament games. Yes they won't have Fat Fritz to try out more ideas but most of the time they will suffice. What's more, not all pro players are on the latest ChessBase software or expensive GPUs! It's nice to have all the latest and baddest but it's not a magic wand towards tournament success.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing a game of chess (in the sense of the term you've explained in the comments) is a complex endeavour. As with most things that involve some degree of complexity, it can't be fully automated. You'll need:

- Knowledge of the subject matter
- Dedicating a certain amount of time and effort

There are certainly tools that can **assist** the user, but in no way **replace** the user. In terms of quality of analysis, they can help a weaker player close the gap with a stronger one, or they can reduce the amount of time it takes to get the desired result. But they cannot do all of the work for you!

In other words, at least in 2022, we can't try to analyze a chess game by "pressing a button" and expect a high quality result. Some sites offer automated analysis features for full games but the results pale in comparison with what an experienced player can do, specially if he's making a proper use of the right tools.

So, what are these tools?

With a game **database**, you can solve most of your opening questions. They can help you learn about the theoretical status of a certain line, alternatives to the moves played in the game and the context for other instances in which the line was played (i.e: when was it played, where, by whom?...)

With a **chess engine** (like Stockfish), you can get a very good approximation of what the outcome of a game will be from a specific position **assuming both sides will play optimally** after that moment. This means engines won't consider moves that may look interesting to a human but have a refutation. A complete analysis which intends to be useful should include that type of moves. In other words, an engine will give you the answers but you're still the one who has to ask the questions. It's like a calculator: it's of no use if you don't know what numbers to input!

An **endgame tablebase** is the "deterministic" version of a chess engine. They will give you the exact outcome (with optimal play) from any posiiton with 7 or fewer pieces. But I think you'll hardly ever need to resort to them in practice.

Finally, you may want to use some **game storage software** to have your analysis properly saved and ordered. Creating studies on Lichess is probably the best free option available.

Comment: what bugs me the most is that the analysis software ‘not the engines’ are still primitive despite having under our control a lot of extremely efficient low-level tools, and yes, those engines when it comes to game analysis are just low-level tools, they have extreme positional-tactical analysis capabilities but no guidance at all, and here I agree with you that “an experienced player” can do a great job analyzing a chess game comprehensively but at what cost? Of time energy and may be money too and for the three reasons I am not interested in that thing even if I become an experienced player

Comment: @WassimSaeed the thing is, the choice is ultimately yours. If you want a good analysis of a game, you'll indeed need time, effort or money. Still if you're not willing to put any of the three you probably don't want your analysis so badly in the first place...